# Magento 2: How to install modules that are not on the marketplace without breaking the setup interface?

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, web-setup-wizard

I have this issue when I go to the "Web Setup Wizard" & try to install extensions that I just bought from the marketplace & it gets stuck because there are some modules that have been installed using `composer require...`.

The only way for me to pass this (for now) is to remove them from the composer.json, run `composer update`, Install the extensions using the "Web Setup Wizard" & then add back the modules I removed.

Is there any "right"/"better" way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue that the web wizard does not work as soon as you used composer on the command line.

Here's a relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6718

It has been fixed in Magento 2.2 and the fix has been backported to the 2.1 branch so that it should work with the latest version.

As a workaround in older versions, you can apply the fix manually, only one file has to be changed: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9692/files